# Markdown inside HTML tags breaks formatting when switching to Rich text mode

Tags: bug, markdown, stacks-editor

This behavior is relevant to the Stacks Editor (used by default in SO Teams, and as an optional mode [here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current)).

How to reproduce:

1. Enter the following text in Markdown (with preview) mode:

```
<sub>text start [link title `inline code`](https://goog.le) text end</sub>
```

> [image: The editor using "Markdown with preview mode" with the above string entered.]

Preview is fine.

2. Switch to Rich text mode:

> [image: The editor has been changed to "Rich text mode". The text is small, and the link is now blue, with underscores for spaces.]

Preview already has some weird link underline.

3. Switch back to Markdown (with preview) mode:

> [image: The editor has been changed back to "Markdown with preview mode". Extra 's and <\sub>'s appear.]

As you can see, the markdown content has been changed, as has the rendered string; several additional `<sub></sub>` blocks have been added.